# Why does the GIF animation stops working when doing an AJAX Call?

Tags: ajax, animation, jquery-ui-dialog, gif

My aim is to show a loading popup (which contains a GIF) while I do an AJAX call.
I am using the [jQuery UI Modal dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal), in which I am inserting the GIF animation using CSS. Before, the AJAX call starts, I am opening the dialog and closing it as soon as the call finishes. The problem is that the GIF stops working when the AJAX call is running and it is happening in all the browsers. I am using the following code:

```
<div id="loadingScreen" title="Loading">Please wait...</div>

#loadingScreen {
    background: url(http://regretless.com/stuff/jQuery/images/loading.gif) no-repeat 5px 8px;
    padding-left: 25px;
}

$("#loadingScreen").dialog('open');
setTimeout(function () {
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "testing.txt",
    async: true,
    dataType: "text",
    success: function (returnText) {
      $("#viewDescription").text(returnText);
      $("#viewGroupID").text(" " + t.id);
      $("#loadingScreen").dialog('close');
      $('#View').dialog('open');
    },
    error: function (xhr, status, error) {
      $("#loadingScreen").dialog('close');
      alert("An error has occured");
    }
  });
}, 10);
```

Can anyone tell me what the problem might be please?

Comment: Can you reproduce this on more than one browser? Are you perchance behind a proxy that would rewrite the image into a non-animated one?

Comment: No, that is not the case for sure because the GIF works before and after the AJAX call

Answer (score 0):

Because this is a background, you need to set focus to #loadingScreen to keep the animation going.

Comment: It didn't make any difference. I tried: `$("#loadingScreen").focus();` and I also tried to remove the image from background by adding an image tag to the `div`: `<img src="http://regretless.com/stuff/jQuery/images/loading.gif" />`; but no luck

Comment: The only other guess is that the request is not actually running in asynchronous mode.

Comment: `async: true`. Don't worry. I actually made a JSP, and from the JSP I am making an AJAX call to a servlet, which reads the text file and then returns the text back. It is now working. Thanks for your time